# switch function in Swift: case vs. case _ where

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem with switch function in Swift, I don't understand why the first code below works but the second one doesn't. Thank you in advance for any help.

First code that works:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    switch (i) {
    case _ where (i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0):
        println("FizzBuzz")
    case _ where i % 3 == 0:
        println("Fizz")
    case _ where i % 5 == 0:
        println("Buzz")
    default:
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Second code that won't work:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    switch (i) {
    case (i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0):
        println("FizzBuzz")
    case i % 3 == 0:
        println("Fizz")
    case i % 5 == 0:
        println("Buzz")
    default:
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because case should be followed by a pattern to be matched against given value, and not a boolean value... Only if the pattern match succeeds, the part after where is additionally checked.

Comment: "`case i where i % 3 == 0:`..."

Comment: Side-note: If every `case` doesn't use pattern matching _(it's matching only against `_` or `let «x»`/`let (x, y)`)_, it makes the most sense to use a `if`/`else if`/`else` instead.  **The `switch`/`case` syntax is designed for pattern matching with occasional `where` conditionals; `if`/`else if`/`else` is designed for straight-up conditionals.**

Answer (score 4):

Your second program uses conditions, such as `(i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)` and `i % 3 == 0`, in place of expression patterns. In this case the `switch` statement will try to match the value of the switch expression (i.e. `i`) to a value of one of these "patterns", which would be either `true` or `false`. Therefore, items that you expected to match the "condition" will fall through to the `default` instead.

The first program uses a missing expression designator `_` for the match pattern, and then guards the execution with the `where <guard-expression>` constant. This is the proper way of doing `switch` statements like that in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this syntax explained in the [Swift Programming Language eBook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11).

The first entity inside a case statement is for pattern matching only, something like a [head of horn clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) in logic programming languages. The where statement is the place where the heavy computation happens (like a [horn clause body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability)).

This is done so that no computation happens before a pattern is matched. This saves some computation time in some cases, but it wouldn't make any difference in your two given examples.